# How to extract the name and the content of a command?

Tags: macros

I realize that the title might be not understandable. I want to have a command `\printit{}` which takes 1 arguments and display it after some test. Inside `\printit` I would like to test if `#1` is just a piece of text, or if it is itself a macro. For simplicity, I could assume the following cases :

- #1 is just some text, like   `hallo`
- #1 has the form `\mycomA{content}`
- #1 has the form `\mycomB{content}`

where `\mycomA{}` and `\mycomB{}` are commands defined by myself. Depending on the case, I want `\printit{}` to typeset `hallo`, or `content` with some formatting depending on the case. 
For simplicity I could also assume that the arguments of `\mycomA`  and `\mycomB` are simple text.

How should I proceed ?  Here is the empty MWE :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycomA}[1]{\textbf{#1}}% just for the example
\newcommand{\mycomB}[1]{\textit{#1}}% just for the example
\newcommand{\printit}[1]{%
% If #1 has the form mycomA(...) THEN 
 case A : content = % extract the content of mycomA
% ElseIf #1 has the form mycomB(...) THEN 
 case B : content = % extract the content of mycomB
% Else THEN 
 case C : content = #1 

\begin{document}
    \printit{hallo}
    \printit{\mycomA{123}}
    \printit{\mycomB{qweqwe}}
    \printit{hallo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me why not to write `\newcommand{\printit}[1]{#1}`. The special formatting is in the definition of `\mycomA` and `\mycomB`, respectively, isn't it? Please elaborate what exactly you wish to achieve.

Comment: no, the formatting is not in the definition of `mycomA`. For example, say, if the argument of `\printit` is `\mycomA`, then print it in red.

Answer (score 6):

If the commands possibly appearing in the argument are of the form `\mycomA` or similar, that is, commands that take an argument, you can prepare a list of them:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\roy@disable}{%
  \let\mycomA\@firstofone
  \let\mycomB\@firstofone
  % other similar commands
}
\newcommand{\printit}[1]{%
  \begingroup\roy@disable
  #1
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

This works because after the group the commands will regain their former definition and `\@firstofone` simply strips off the braces from the argument.

If there's less control on the macros that can appear a more complicated approach must be taken.

### Edit

Let me do some guesswork. You want to have `\printit` treat differently the argument passed to it with respect to the "outer" definition of `\mycomA` and `\mycomB`. Let's say that it has to change `\mycomA` into "print in red" and return "status A", and `\mycomB` to print its argument in green and return "status B":

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\roy@change}{%
  \def\mycomA##1{\gdef\roy@status{A}\textcolor{red}{##1}}
  \def\mycomB##1{\gdef\roy@status{B}\textcolor{green}{##1}}
  % possibly other similar definitions
}
\newcommand{\printit}[1]{\gdef\status{0}% in case no command appears
  \begingroup
  \roy@change
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: no, the replacement text of my `\mycomA` is more complicated. But why not using the same trick, by redefining, in `roy@disable`,  `\mycomA` by something like `\let\mycomA{\gdef\case{A}\gdef\content{\@firstofone}}` , in order to store the content in `\content` and the information about which command was used in `\case` ?

Comment: @nicolasroy Of course you're right: what must be disabled are just the "wrapper" macros. Please, make clearer whether your aim is *not* simply to print the argument.

Comment: ok. But how can i store `\case{A}` ? I can't put the `\@firstofone` in braces ...

Comment: You can redefine `\mycomA` to be whatever you like. It's hard to say more without knowing more of what you want to do. Please, state clearly your problem.

Comment: Well i would like to redefine it e.g. like `\let\mycomA{\gdef\case{A}\gdef\content{\@firstofone}}`. But this does not compile, because my syntaxe is probably incorrect.

Comment: @nicolasroy That code is meaningless. I'll ask another time: what do you *really* want to achieve?

Comment: @nicolasroy The correct syntax is `\renewcommand\mycomA[1]{\gdef\case{A}\gdef\content{##1}}`. But as @egreg says, it is incomprehensible what your're getting at with this.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i wanted. I could vote for this solution... :) About your questions, in my code `\printit` displays his arguments in a tikz figure, inside nodes, and `\mycomA` is just an indicator for `\printit`, that the node should have some particular style. This is why i can't put this style directly in the command `\mycomA`.

Answer (score 3):

I would just redefine `\mycomA` and `\mycomB`, respectively, to the way they should be printed by `\printit`:

```
\newcommand\printit[1]{%
  \begingroup
     \renewcommand\mycomA[1]{\textcolor{red}{##1}}%
     \renewcommand\mycomB[1]{\textcolor{blue}{##1}}%
     #1%
  \endgroup
}%
```